# How to handle listener on click out side on Pop window in Android?

Tags: android

I would handle the listener when the user clicks outside Popup window to implement the way of dismissing popup window with animation. What do I have to do for this purpose?

```
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow();
popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code snippets so we can look into it and help you.

Comment: @starrydeveloper I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override `onWindowFocusChanged`:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

outside of popup, you can click this method return value you can use value and set popup animation and close your popup

Comment: I would like the handle event in custom Pop up window.